# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' when `python app.py` but working well with `sudo python app.py`

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service= Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url = "https://www.naver.com/"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
```

The above is my code (app.py in project root).
My computer is Mac m1.
I tried these on terminal,

1. `python -m venv venv`
2. `. venv/bin/activate`
3. `pip install selenium`
4. `pip install webdriver_manager`

After those, I tried `python app.py` but this error occurred.

```
(venv) [~/Desktop/leetcode-auto-bookmark]$ python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/obzva/Desktop/leetcode-auto-bookmark/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

So I tried these,

1. Check whether python version and pip version are match or not
2. Upgrade pip
3. Reinstall selenium and webdriver_manager

But it didn't work...!

I just typed `sudo python app.py` and all of a sudden, app.py worked.

Can you explain why this thing happens?

`python --version` and `sudo python --version` is same.

Comment: Try `which python` and `sudo which python` or `sudo -c "which python"`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use conda.

```
conda install selenium
```

Sometimes it works for me when I can't install or run some module.
I don't know why it works that way, but conda is more stable.